# Any working php debugger, PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, phpstorm

Honestly, I am tired of searching and trying various php debuggers and IDEs from netbeans to jetbrains PHP storm, Eclipse indigo, WAMP, (old zend server community edition) etc!
 I need a working set of IEDs and debuggers so I can start developing my work!( I by the way want to develop php scripts in Windows)
 Problems:

- [php storm: weird IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/)]
- [PHP Tools for Visual Studio: it says it is free, but you can try it for free for 30 days](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5)
- [PDT Eclipse: too old, no updates, broken links. Working with Zend itself is creepy](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/)
- [Netbeans 7.3, still not easy to work with. So many settings Xdebug not working](http://netbeans.org/features/php/)

I need something like PHP development tools for Eclipse Juno, any suggestions?

What combinations of IDE(netbeans, phpstorm, Eclipse, Visual stodio) + (Zned server, XDebug) do you guys use? I am really tired of this product not being compatible with one another.

Comment: All IDEs you have mentioned working OK with xdebug and Zend debugger. The fact that "it is confusing" and you have not managed to figure out how it works does not mean that they are not working. **And BTW**: Notepad++, Dreamweaver etc are NOT IDE -- just advanced text editors (excluding Nusphere -- it is an IDE).

Comment: Nusphere is a bit costly and who knows it might also have same issues too! plus, our discussion here is not what looking for a right definition for what is IDE and what is not.

Comment: True -- this Q is not about what IDE and what is not. But almost all answers were about text editors.. Anyway -- regarding an actual **IDE**: `PhpStorm` supports both xdebug and Zend Debugger; same with `Netbeans` -- I've used both of them with xdebug and had no issues AT ALL making **debugger** work (I'm using xdebug and IIS 7).

Answer (score 3):

I would really give PhpStorm another try. True, it takes a bit of time to get used to, but it offers a lot of features that are hard to find in other IDEs

Regarding debugging and testing, read these walk-throughs on debugging:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

And unit testing:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHPUnit+Installation+via+Composer+in+PhpStorm

### Simple Texteditor

Apart from a proper IDE, I always have a 'regular' text editor 'on the side', for example to have a quick 'scratch' file to write down some notes, or to make minor changes in a file without having to open your entire project.

There are many nice editors, [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) are some examples.

### Test and development environment

Although using WAMP/XAMP is convenient to set up, it is **not** the best environment to test your project. Most PHP websites will be hosted on a Linux/Using environment, which is quite **different** from a Windows environment in many ways, some are:

- Linux/Unix file systems are *Case Sensitive*, whereas Windows is not
- Linux/Unix uses a *slash* `/` as directory separator, Windows uses *backslashes* `\`
- Some parts of PHP rely on functionality provided by the operating system. Therefore PHP will produce different results on Windows than on Linux/Unix
- Linux/Unix uses a different permission system

If you develop and test your websites on WAMP you **will** encounter unwelcome surprises when you try to deploy the website on the actual hosting environment. **Some problems may not even present themselves instantly**, which will even be worse (customer calling in the middle of your Holiday telling you that the 'flush cache' admin-panel flushed not only the cache, but also all uploaded content)

So, in order to properly develop and test your website, your development environment **should match the targeted hosting environment as *close as possible***

Inform with your hosting provider what their environment looks like; What Linux distribution are they using? (CentOS? Ubuntu?) What versions of PHP, Apache, MySQL?

Set up your test environment according to this. Either by setting up a development server and installing Linux on that, or running a Virtual Machine on your workstation, for example VMWare or Parallels Desktop (a virtual machine may save you some time, because many pre-installed, ready to use LAMP disk-images exist)

### Client side testing

Preferably, make sure you have some computers or virtual machines with a **clean install** of your targeted audience (Windows XP, Vista? etc) sometimes a clean install is missing plugins/functionality that you assumed are present, causing problems (no Adobe Reader installed? No Flash? Old version of Windows Media Player?)

If your targeted audience are business users, be sure to test your website in the *actual* environment. Think of pitfalls like Caching Proxy Servers, Firewalls, multiple IP-addresses, disabled JavaScript and Thin Clients (using Remote Desktop). Sometimes those environments are still using Internet Explorer 7 (even 6) because of company policy.

Comment: +1 for comprehensive answer and good calls to remember while developing any web application. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver is by far the best php writting tool, the color code is amazing and the auto complete features are irreplaceable. The only other program i have seen come close in the field of auto complete is zend and that lagged like no other. plus it has built in ftp AND it makes it pretty easy to move on to javascript (IMO)
As far as server software i personally favorite WAMP, but everyone will have their own preference

you can find dreamweaver(trial) [here](http://success.adobe.com/en/na/sem/products/dreamweaver.html?kw=p&sdid=JRSIQ&skwcid=AL!3085!3!23343671683!b!!g!dreamweaver%20cs3&ef_id=USxMOgAAAcHQDAIP:20130330034729%3as)

Wampp is [here](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (pretty sweet webpage):

Comment: Wow look how wrong I was all those years ago, don't use a WYSIWYG editor (dreamweaver), I 10/10 recommend PHPStorm

Answer (score 1):

For PHP, I'd use Notepad++ all the way due to dynamic typing instead of static.
Notepad++ is quite light-weight and won't be in your way.

What sort of debugging do you need? Heavy unit testing and profiling or just print_r type of debugging? Have you tried http://www.firephp.org/ ? It's an extension to Firebug that works really well with AJAX.

Comment: good call, firephp. thanks. I am looking for a PDT where i can place stop points, whatch variables' values etc

Answer (score 0):

I use Dreamweaver and Xampp, and occasionally Notepad+++ and Xampp.

As stated in the thread, Dreamweaver has a great color code system and is very user friendly.  I suggest it.

- [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)
- [Notepad](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no Eclipse juno PDT . The latest one is for indigo and that one crashes from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use of Nusphere php ide , its too great for php, it has auto complete features and in built server and you can debug run time, you can also set browser foo debugging your code , its true php debugger, i am using this debugger since last 3years ,its amazing and it has inbuilt ftp feature so you can also debug your ftp file.

Here is link [Nusphere](http://www.nusphere.com/)